# Will CSS3PIE .htc file load for other browsers even they don't need?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, css3pie

I'm using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) to make round corners in IE which uses invalid CSS property

```
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

If i keep this declarition in my main CSS will other browsers load this .htc file even they don't need this or only IE will load this file?

Is there any benefit to keep `behavior: url(/PIE.htc);`is seperate IE conditional stylesheet in terms of performance?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

The whole code is like this

```
border: 1px solid #696;
padding: 60px 0;
text-align: center; width: 200px;
-webkit-border-radius: 8px;
-moz-border-radius: 8px;
border-radius: 8px;
background: #EEFF99;
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545501/how-to-load-css3-pie-only-for-ie7-and-8-but-not-for-9

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The spec says that [browsers are to completely ignore declarations whose property names they don't recognize](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#parsing-errors). This means, theoretically, that since `behavior` is an IE-only property, the `url()` should not be parsed, and the file not be downloaded by browsers other than IE.

I ran a test on IE9 and Firefox 4, loading [the CSS3 PIE tabs demo](http://css3pie.com/demos/tabs), and here's what F12 Developer Tools and Firebug show respectively in their network tabs. Notice that Firebug reports no attempt to request the `/PIE.htc` file. That means Firefox didn't load the file even though it was declared in your stylesheet, because it doesn't recognize the `behavior` property.

**IE9 (F12 Developer Tools)**

[image]

**Firefox 4 (Firebug)**

[image]

The only reason I'd move that property to an IE-only stylesheet with conditional comments is if I don't want to pollute my main stylesheet with non-standard properties and/or hacks.

Comment: But as IE9 support default CSS 3 border radius property then will it render the corners using .htc file or it will use css for broder-readius?

Comment: @Jitendra Vyas: Not too sure. If you want you can move the `behavior` to a separate stylesheet that IE9 won't see.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary. The `behavior` property is as invalid to all the other browsers as `-moz-border-radius` is to IE. You may want to use the latter method to prevent IE9 from loading the behavior though, but the market share is not sufficient to care right now.

Answer (score 1):

*An updated answer (February 2014) since it seems a rather unclear topic.*

The way it works is that you trigger the load of the HTC library via the "behavior" property.

**"behavior" is an IE6-9 property only**, [see MS official website "Support for element behaviors and HTML components (HTCs) has been removed in Internet Explorer 10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and compliance with HTML5."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Hence, the "behavior" property could only trigger the load of anything when used on IE6-9.

The library ***should*** never be loaded for IE10+ NOR for other browsers (ie. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, & so on)

I have tested in the same way as @BoltClock & found that nor the htc, nor the js was loaded when I was **not** on an IE6-9 browser, as expected. I tested on IE8, IE9, Chrome 32, IE11, & Firefox 27 (see screenshots below).

I'll try to spend some more time testing this further, maybe I missed something.
In the meantime, anyone can test using the official demo page [css3pie.com/demos/](http://css3pie.com/demos/) & [browserstack.com](http://www.browserstack.com/) (they have a free trial) for instance.

Chrome, Firefox & IE11 are not loading the css3pie js library, as expected:
[image: Chrome 12]

[image: Firefox 32]

[image: IE11]
Note: the "dynamisch skripts" directory list the javascript added directly inside the page (not referenced to a separated js file)

IE9 loads a css3pie js library, as expected:
[image: IE9]

IE8 loads a css3pie js library, as expected:
[image: IE8]

Note 1: note that the lib loaded for IE8 or for IE9 is different.

Note 2: chrome, firefox & IE11 do not load any css3pie library but may load some css3pie CSS, this might need further testing.