# Modernizr, html5shiv, ie7.js, and CSS3 Pie. Which to use and when?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, modernizr, css3pie

I'm just starting to use HTML5 and CSS3 in my documents. 
I understand the need for JavaScript to bring Internet Explorer up to speed with these new tags and styles, but I don't know which to use and when!

My plan was to use html5shiv and IE9.js to look after the HTML5 tags as well as the transparent pngs (and whatever other pesky errors they fix) but then Modernizr and CSS3 Pie were brought to my attention.

My question is, if I use Modernizr, does it look after my need for html5shiv as well as IE9.js? Or should I include these as well? What is the overlap, if any?

And what does CSS3 Pie do that Modernizr or the others doesn't? Or vice versa?

I appreciate your guys help. Let me know what you do!?

Comment: See also a very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855294/html5shiv-vs-dean-edwards-ie7-js-vs-modernizr-which-to-choose/3855343#3855343

Comment: regarding CSS3PIE, you don't need to use Modernizr to do "conditional JS loading" since only IE browsers up to 9 will load the PIE library. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609651/will-css3pie-htc-file-load-for-other-browsers-even-they-dont-need and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545501/how-to-load-css3-pie-only-for-ie7-and-8-but-not-for-9

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I've got extensive experience with all of these, having used them for a few years each.

**Modernizr**

Includes HTML5shiv functionality
Also does a lot more – if you don't use the other features, then don't use it, it does slow down page loads, but is worth it if you need it!

**HTML5shiv**

Very small, just fixes html5 elements in IE, nothing else.

**CSS3PIE**

Lets you use border-radius, gradients and box shadow in older versions of IE. Also can allow PNGs in IE 6. Adds a noticeable delay to page load.

**ie7.js (and ie9.js)**

Gives you many CSS3 selectors, min and max width, multiple classes and fixed positioning. Also can have a png fix if you like. Doesn't seem to slow things down much.

**Conclusion**

My advice would fall into two categories:

If you are just using the new (is 2 years new on the internet?!) elements, and CSS3 selectors, then use ie9.js + the html5shiv. This is lightweight, and just lets you get on with things without having to remember that IE6 doesn't support anything.

If you are using a lot of CSS3 stuff, then CSS3PIE will sort out border-radius and box-shadow. The gradient support seems a little flaky, so I've always used a fallback image instead. Modernizr lets you easily deliver different properties to browsers with different support. I've mainly used this for determining whether a browser has CSS transitions and transforms, as they are useful for any image sliders or content carousels. It's worth using the customisation tool to only include the functionality that you want – the webforms stuff shows a textbox with 50 in it for a couple of milliseconds, so it's worth disabling if you don't want it.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Very helpful indeed! Thank you. One last question, I understand from what you're saying that if I choose to use Modernizr, it will fulfill the need for html5shiv, but what about ie9.js? If I use Modernizr, should I still use html5shiv to look after transparent pngs etc? And same goes for CSS3 PIE, does it look after the functionality of either html5shiv or ie9.js? I want to use only what I need for the page, so knowing what would be redundant would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend you use only what you need. Build your app in a browser that supports the features you are using, and periodically test in other browsers that you support. If something isn't working correctly, find the appropriate fix, whether it be html5shiv, IE9.js, Modernizr, or CSS3 Pie. You are not going to use all of the new features in HTML5 and CSS3 all in one page, so you don't need to include every polyfill library in existence. Wait until you find problems with the features you're trying to use, then try and find the library necessary to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I've used mainly CSS3Pie...it works great. But this afternoon i tested it on my laptop with I.E8 and there was an problem with it...it was disabling some css lines...when i removed the css3pie code my site gained twice the speed...then i came accross the posts with people arguing about the css3 slowdown...So at the moment i'm busy to find another way for IE7 & IE8 to have border-radius and shades.

If you want to use it...please test alot as it is NON-official fixes

Comment: The alternatives for IE7-IE8 are to not have rounded corners, or switch to images...  (Though, you could use some of the underlying techniques behind css3pie.  I've lately gone to simply not rounding borders for legacy browsers.  I use modernizr + ie9.js myself, as I'll use a lot of the additional targets modernizr gives.